# Pass 'name' as parameter in YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a YAML file as follows:

```
name: $(major).$(minor).$(Date:yyMM).$(Rev:r)

trigger:
- develop
- main
- master
- users/*

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  "major": '2'
  "minor": '0'

stages:

- template: build.yml
  parameters:
    tagName: 
    repoToCheckout: ''
    checkoutPath: ''
```

Is there a way to pass `name` as a value of `tagName` parameter?

On trying

> tagName: $(major).$(minor).$(Date:yyMM).$(Rev:r)

I get the error:

[image]

Comment: You may try these                                                                                          `variables:
- name: one
  value: initialValue `
and
`-script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue`
see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch")

Comment: You can just: `tagName: $(Build.BuildNumber)`

Comment: Thank you! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set

> tagName: $(Build.BuildNumber)